# Disqus anchor links “#disqus_thread” don’t work

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, blogger, disqus

When visiting my blog urls with Disqus anchor link (e.g. ***url-to/my-blog-post#disqus_thread***) the browser doesn’t scroll down to the `<div id="disqus_thread">` element.

Instead, if I am already on the page ***url-to/my-blog-post*** and click the link to ***url-to/my-blog-post#disqus_thread*** it scrolls down to the `div`.

I thought it was a loading problem. The browser visit the page and doesn’t find the `div` element, as it is still to be generate by the Disqus JS.
I tried to change the position of the JS code but nothing changed.

This is a sample post url from my blog:
https://2bluebuffalo-en.blogspot.com/2018/11/how-to-crop-square-video-macos.html#disqus_thread
It doesn’t work, but if you click the link next to “By Blue Buffalo” (above the share buttons, now it’s written ”2 Comments”) the anchor link works.

---

### Workaround

Ok, that’s the workaround I have found. It works just good. Just in case someone is going to click that link.

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
 var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  if (hash == "disqus_thread") {
    location.hash = "#comments";
    location.hash = "#" + hash;
  };
}, 1000);
</script>
```

The waiting is because it takes me one sec. to load everything (sometimes even more). It can be changed.

Comment: How about using #comments instead?

Comment: Hi @IanGilroy thank you. It works using #comments. The problem is I do not have the Disqus JS file that adds automatically #disqus_thread at the end of the link. So I cannot change the link href to ***path/to/post#comments***.

Comment: @Umberto you can Edit the HTML of the blog to add the disqus script!

Comment: Thank you @Gourav
I tried that, but actually seems that the Disqus plugin is loaded only when the user go down. Or at least nothing really changed. So I preferred to maintain the original configuration and add that script above.

Do you use Disqus on Blogger too?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this hack:

Edit the HTML of the blog and add the Disqus scripts. For your comments, you can do this:

```
<div id = "comments">
    <div id = "disqus_thread"></div>
</div>
```

This will take you to the comments section and load the Disqus comments.